Bauer's series for $\frac{1}{\pi}$
Recently, someone asked a question involving the expression
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (4n+1) \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^3 $$
At first glance, I knew that the expression was the value of a hypergeometric function, and anticipated difficulty in determining its exact value. Surprisingly, the value obtained using Mathematica was $\frac{2}{\pi}$. He couldn't recall the context in which the formula appeared well. (He mentioned seeing the expression in a comic book!) However, at this point, I suspect this may be a series studied by Ramanujan.
Interestingly, when variables are introduced into the expression, as the following
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n (4n+1) \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^3 $$
a very complicated hypergeometric function emerges, Nonetheless, Mathematica was unable to simplify the expression obtained by substituting $x=-1$ to revert to the original form.
Therefore, I believe that the result might be derived from something like a complex contour integral or a similar method, and might not be readily analyzed as a special value of a hypergeometric function.
Please help in understanding the reasoning behind the evaluation of this series.

This is Bauer's series sent by Ramanujan to Hardy in one of his letters. Has been solved here using Clausen's formula for $K^2(k)$ and also for $E(k)K(k)$ and $E(k')K(k')$ in combination with Legendre's relation  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107321/how-to-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n4n12n326nn6/4898944#4898944
Check the solution.

This series is of a different breed in comparison with others you can find in the famous paper Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$ where Ramanujan used elliptic functions to calculate similar series.
Instead, your series appears in the chapter one of Hardy's book: Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work with the number (1.2)
$$ 1-5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + 9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^3-13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^3+... = \frac{2}{\pi} \tag{1.2} $$
In that book Hardy gave a hint of how the formula can be proven:

The series formulae (1.1)-(1.4) I found much more intriguing, and it soon became obvious that Ramanujan must possess much more general theorems and was keeping a great deal up his sleeve. The second (1.2) is a formula of Bauer well known in the theory of Legrende series, but the others are much harder than they look.

Following Hardy's advice, the relation can be proved using the theory of Legendre polynomials.
Consider the Legrende polynomials defined with the Rodrigues’ formula:
$$ P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x^2-1)^n \tag{1} $$
If $f(x)$ is a very smooth function in $|x|\leq 1$ then it can be expanded in terms of Legendre polynomials:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nP_n(x) $$
where
$$ a_n = \frac{2n+1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} P_n(x) f(x) dx $$
Consider function  $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}$. We will show that this function has the following expansion in Legendre polynomials:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(1 + 5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 P_{2}(x) +9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^2P_4(x) + 13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^2 P_6(x)+... \right)  $$
First, we have to calculate the coefficients:
$$a_n =  \frac{2n+1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{P_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \tag{*}$$
This can be proven by induction:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_n(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } = \begin{cases}
 \displaystyle \pi \left[\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}\right]^2 & \quad n=2m , \;\; m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\\
 \displaystyle 0  &\quad n=2m+1, \;\; m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0} 
\end{cases}$$
For that end, these properties of the Legrende polynomials are needed:
$$ P_n(x) = \frac{2n-1}{n} xP_{n-1}(x) - \frac{n-1}{n} P_{n-2}(x) \tag{2}$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} P_n(x) = \frac{n}{1-x^2} \left[P_{n-1}(x) -xP_n(x) \right] \tag{3} $$
Base case. $m=0$
By the Rodrigues’ formula:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_0(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=& \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }\\
 & =& \arcsin(1)-\arcsin(-1) = \pi 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_1(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=& \int_{-1}^1 \frac{tdt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }\\
 & =& \left[-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]_{-1}^1 = 0 
\end{eqnarray*}
Inductive step. Suppose this is valid for $m=k$
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_n(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } = \begin{cases}
 \displaystyle \pi \left[\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}\right]^2 & \quad n=2k \\
 \displaystyle 0  &\quad n=2k+1 
\end{cases}$$
We have to prove it for $m=k+1$
From the recurrence formula (2) and the inductive step:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2k+2}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=&  \frac{4k+3}{2k+2}\int_{-1}^1 t\frac{P_{2k+1}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }- \frac{2k+1}{2k+2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2k}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }  \\
 &=&  \frac{4k+3}{2k+2}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{tP_{2k+1}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }- \pi \frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now integrating by parts and using (3):
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{tP_{2k+1}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=& (2k+1)\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}P'_{2k+1}(t)dt \\
 &=& (2k+1)\int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{ 2k}(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt - (2k+1)\int_{-1}^1 \frac{tP_{ 2k+1}(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt 
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, by the inductive step:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{tP_{2k+1}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=& \frac{ (2k+1)}{(2k+2)} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{ 2k}(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = \pi \frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2k+2}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=&  \frac{4k+3}{2k+2}\int_{-1}^1 t\frac{P_{2k+1}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }- \frac{2k+1}{2k+2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2k}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }  \\
 &=&  \pi \frac{(4k+3)}{(2k+2)} \frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} -  \pi \frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}   \\
 &=& \pi \left[ \frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\right]^2
\end{eqnarray*}
In a similar way you can show  as an exercise that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2k+3}(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} } &=&  0
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, from (*) we have:
$$ a_{2m} = \frac{(4m-1)\pi}{2} \left[\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}\right]^2  $$
$$ a_{2m+1} =0$$
Then, we have proved:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(1 + 5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 P_{2}(x) +9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^2P_4(x) + 13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^2 P_6(x)+... \right)  $$
If $x=0$.
$$ \frac{2}{\pi} =1 + 5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 P_{2}(0) +9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^2P_4(0) + 13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^2 P_6(0)+...   $$
by the recurrence formula (2) with $x=0$ :
$$ P_{2m}(0) = -\frac{2m-1}{2m} P_{2m-2}(0) $$
Iterating
$$ P_{2m}(0) = (-1)^{m}\frac{(2m-1)}{2m}\frac{(2m-3)}{(2m-2)}\cdots \frac{1}{2} = (-1)^{m} \frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}$$
Finally
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}=  1-5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + 9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^3-13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^3+...  $$

The series is actually in the same breed as other series given by Ramanujan is his paper. You can check Ramanujan's approach given in answer which is referenced in comments to this question.

@ParamanandSingh Hi, I actually don't mean that Ramanujan proved this series using a different method: I'm not sure if there is evidence of that or if Ramanujan was aware of the theory of Legendre polynomials. However, IMO it's different because Hardy thought the same: the proof of this series was known to European mathematicians at least since 1859 and it was a muuuch simpler proof than the proof of other series posted by  Ramanujan and developed by other mathematicians in subsequent years.

My best guess is that Ramanujan was probably aware of the series, but not of the proof by Fourier Legendre expansion. And yes Ramanujan's technique (and theory behind it) is way more difficult. BTW I had forgot to upvote last time. So +1

@ParamanandSingh Yes, or probably Hardy told Ramanujan about Bauer's proof and that was the reason why Ramanujan decided to not include that particular series in Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$ in 1914

@ParamanandSingh At first glance, I thought this answer was yours. :)

@TitoPiezasIII: most of my answers involving Ramanujan's work mention about his 1914 paper on modular equations. So maybe a similar mention at the start of this answer made you think like that.

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\, (4n+1) \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^3$$ $$S=\frac{1}{\pi ^{3/2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\, (4n+1)\left(\frac{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n+1)}\right)^3 $$ So, an hypergeometric function is expected.
$$S=\left(\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{8}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}\right)^2-\frac 12 \,\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac
   {3}{2};2,2;-1\right)=\frac 2 \pi$$
Now
$$T=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\, (4n+1) \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^3\, x^n$$
$$T=\frac 4 {\pi^2}\Bigg(K\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1-\sqrt{x+1}\right)\right)\Bigg)^2-\frac x2 \,\,,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac
   {3}{2};2,2;-x\right)$$ Checked numerically
$$\frac 2 \pi\,K\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)=\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{8}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
All of the above looks very consistent.

I have some difficulty to understand your solution. The third line is just a claim, right? I cannot understand how the fifth line obtained where the elliptic function is introduced. What do you mean by 'numerically'?

@seoneo. How do you construct, from definition, a generalized hypergeometric function ? This is exactly why I immediately introduced the gamma function. Concerning the cas of the fifth line, this is a result from Mathematice. To check the last line I computed the difference with 10,000 significant figures.

I have already obtained the same results as you described using Mathematica. However, what I am looking for is not a method to check this equation with the help of a computer. Rather, I am seeking proofs that we humans can write and follow. And furthermore, I want to understand how to discover such equations.

It is far from a demonstration.
